# Вопрос по абстрактной фабрике (созданию объектов разных классов)

Tags: java, классы, наследование

Есть базовый абстрактный класс Tank - у него есть какие-то параметры и конструктор. Создается класс-наследник LightTank с новым параметром armor, в конструкторе все параметры конкретизируются. Как сделать фабрику танков, чтобы в зависимости от входящего слова LIGHT, MEDIUM, HEAVY создавались бы объекты LightTank, MediumTank, HeavyTank отличающиеся только значениями параметров?

```
abstract public class Tank {...}
public class LightTank extends Tank{
private int armor;
public int getArmor() { return armor;}

public Tank createTank(String model) {
if (model.equals("LIGHT")) return new LightTank;
else if....
```

Comment: Так а в чем проблемма то? Переопределите значение armor в конструктора каждого дочернего класса и все.

Comment: Если возвращает класс Tank в нем нет же поля armor?

Comment: А где вы потом хотите использовать эти поля, и почему они вам нужны извне? Не проще ли сделать виртуальный метод и переопределить его соответствующим образом в каждом классе?

Comment: Хотелось бы их закрыть, чтобы был доступ только через геттер и сеттер, если перенести в танк и сделать их private, то как им дать значение при инициализации, при этом setArmore нельзя делать, так как armore задается один раз и больше не меняется. Я новичок и не все знаю, если им поставить final то можно один раз в наследнике - классе LightTank задать параметру armore значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю Вы хотите что то типа

```
abstract public class Tank {
 int getArmor();   
}

public class LightTank extends Tank {

    private int armor;

    public LightTank() {
     armor = 10;   
    }
    public int getArmor() {
        return armor;
    }
}
public class HeavyTank extends Tank {

    private int armor;

    public HeavyTank() {
     armor = 100;   
    }
    public int getArmor() {
        return armor;
    }
}
// фабрика    
    public Tank createTank(String model) {
        if (model.equals("LIGHT")) {
            return new LightTank();
        } else if (model.equals("HEAVY")) {
            return new HeavyTank();

}
...
// получим значение armor для абстрактного танка
tank.getArmor();
```

Comment: Дома вечером попробую и отпишусь, спасибо